# Laravel. Нужно, чтобы пользователь видел только свои экземпляры сущностей

Tags: php, laravel

Вечер добрый!

Схема приложения такая:
имеются пользователи, которые создают кампании. У кампании есть зависимые сущности.

Как правильно сделать так, чтобы авторизованный пользователь видел только свои экземпляры сущностей?
Можно ли это сделать на уровне модели?

Comment: Можно у модели каждой кампании (или компании, если грамматическая ошибка в вопросе) добавить новый филд а-ля `CreatedUserId` и делать выборку по нему.

Comment: @AGS17 , этот-то момент понятен. Но в этом случае нарушится архитектура приложения, надеялся, что есть более грамотные способы решения этого вопроса, нежели переписывание всех методов репозитория под каждый контроллер с учетом связей.

Comment: Так может покажите тогда архитектуру? Не знаем же, как у вас это работает...

Comment: @AGS17, думаю, Вы сможете помочь, если только работали с laravel.
Вообще, архитектура проста: Контроллеры -> бизнес слой -> слой репозиториев -> слой моделей.
Выборка по пользователю должна быть, скорее всего, на слое репозитория. Сейчас репозиторий каждой сущности наследуется от родителя - репозитория, который содержит общие методы. При этом способ получения данных о компании(которая связана с пользователем-создателем) может быть разным у разных сущностей.
Я не знаю, как более внятно описать архитектуру.

Comment: Не работал с laravel (я не php). По вашим рассказам у вас стандартный трехслойник, поэтому вам протягивать надо авторизационного товарища на BL слое. Ибо никак он к репозиториям в принципе отностится не должен.

Comment: @AGS17 спасибо за совет!